# How to use layouts in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

Aurelia recently added support for layouts, and they roughly explained those [in their documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/10).

However, while I managed to get the layouting itself to work, I cannot use any variables in my layout-HTML which I have as properties in my Layout-ViewModel.

A MWE:

**app.ts**

```ts
import {Router, RouterConfiguration} from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
  router: Router;

  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.map([
      { route: 'hello', layoutViewModel: 'layout/main', moduleId: 'hello/index' },
    ]);
  }
}
```

**layout/main.ts**

```
export class MainLayout {
  heading = 'Hallo Welt';
}
```

**layout/main.html**

```
<template>
  <h1>${heading}!</h1>
</template
```

But only the exclamation point occurs. Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong or how I can get it to work?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a plunker?

Comment: Your moduleId is `hello/index` aren't you supposed to be doing the assigning in `hello/index` and not `layout/main` ?

Comment: @MrBones but I want to provide a ViewModel to my layout, not to the `hello/index` module

Comment: Can you set up a plunkr code or something to work with ?

Try changing `moduleId` to `layoutModel`. Might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue on github about very same problem
https://github.com/aurelia/templating-router/issues/34 
It has been resolved and now layoutViewModel binds just fine.

Comment: Thanks for updating me on this! Unfortunately, I haven't been working with Aurelia for a while, and I lost track of this question, so sorry for my delayed response.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delayed answer here, but your example appears to be working for me. It is highly possible that you experienced a bug that has since been fixed or an issue elsewhere in your code.

Please see [this linked Gist.run example](https://gist.run/?id=95476d8efa129392ec15aa50bc0c073f) to see your example running.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in layout/main.ts:

```
export class MainLayout {
  constructor() {
    this.heading = 'Hallo Welt';
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is what my TypeScript code would compile to.